# What are Element Style Components and What are Fragment Style Components?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like to know the difference between Element Style Components and Fragment Style Components ,precisely what is meant by Element Style Components and what is meant by Fragment Style Components? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<my-component>` vs `{{my-component}}`?

Comment: no not angle bracket components; but i did read it in that RFC that angle bracket component unifies Element Style Components and Fragment Style Components , I didn't understand What is meant by Element Style & Fragment Style Components in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all [Element and Fragment RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/37#issuecomment-109788051) was superseded by [Component Unification (angle brackets)](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/60), so if you want to track this subject check the latter.

In very simple words, `Ember.Fragment` is a tagless component. Presently if you don't want a component to have a surrounding `div` you have to do `tagName=""` which is a bit hacky. `Ember.Fragment` was an attempt at a better API to declare that.

`Ember.Element` in turn was an attempt at a declarative API for specifying the root DOM element of your component in your template, instead of relying on JavaScript.

From what I understand of `Component Unification`, angle bracket components will replace the invocation of the component with its content, unlike currently where the wrapping DOM element is managed by Ember. Fun RFC to follow along!